# ftell on a file descriptor?

Tags: linux, file-descriptor, ftell, file-pointer

Is there a way to do what ftell() does (return the current position in the file) on a raw file descriptor instead of a FILE*? I think there ought to be, since you can seek on a raw file descriptor using lseek().

I know I could use fdopen() to create a FILE* corresponding to the file descriptor, but I'd rather not do that.

Answer (score 90, accepted):

Just use:

```
position = lseek(fd, 0, SEEK_CUR);
```

Comment: For file length, `lseek(fd, 0, SEEK_END);`

Comment: @SF.By the way, would it be better to use `fstat` or `lseek` for the size of a file?

Comment: @SF. note that this will also move the file descriptor to the end of the file if it is not located there yet, which is not necessarily what you want.

Comment: @YiLinLiu: It seems that fstat gathers a lot more info about the file than just size. Use stat if you want just to learn about a file but don't open it; lseek if you open the file and need just the size, fstat if you open the file and need more than just the size.