# Get position for file descriptor in Python

Tags: python, file, ftell

Say, I have a raw numeric file descriptor and I need to get the current position in file based on it.

```
import os, psutil

# some code that works with file
lp = lib.open('/path/to/file')

p = psutil.Process(os.getpid())
fd = p.get_open_files()[0].fd  # int

while True:
    buf = lp.read()
    if buf is None:
        break
    device.write(buf)
    print tell(fd)  # how to find where we are now in the file?
```

In the following code `lib` is a compiled library, that doesn't give access to the file object. In the loop I use the embedded method `read` which returns the processed data. The data and it's length doesn't relate to the file position, so I can't calculate the offset mathematically.

I tried to use `fdopen`, as `fd = fdopen(p.get_open_files()[0].fd)`, but `print fd.tell()` returned only the first position in the file, which was not updating in the loop.

Is there a way to get the current real time position in a file based on file descriptor?

Comment: I think you're a bit confused on your comments ;) (should be ```#```)

Comment: @wnnmaw Yeah, damned C `:D`

Comment: Might it be the case that the file you're reading from is not the first open by this process and it's like `p.get_open_files()[1]` etc.

Comment: @bereal No, it is the only opened file in the script. Anyway, the solution is found. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, the answer seems to be quite easy. I had to use [`os.lseek`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.lseek) with `SEEK_CUR` flag:

```
import os
print(os.lseek(fd, 0, os.SEEK_CUR))
```

I don't know if it is the only approach, but at least it works fine.

**INTERPRETED:** [ftell on a file descriptor?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3399236/1249581)